# Sequelize association methods attribures

Tags: javascript, sql, database, sequelize.js

I have a struggle with associations method. I have users and lists with many to many association, so the sequelize generate for me method user.getLists(); But when I call that mehod result is

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Boop",
        "created_at": "2018-08-15T14:53:51.276Z",
        "updated_at": "2018-08-15T14:53:51.276Z",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "user_list": {
            "owner": true,
            "created_at": "2018-08-15T14:53:51.290Z",
            "updated_at": "2018-08-15T14:53:51.290Z",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "user_id": 1,
            "list_id": 1
        }
    }
]
```

And I can't find a way to remove `user_list` attribute from it or rename it.
Is there a way to remove this attribute on ORM level or rename it?

For example this is not working:

```
user.getLists({ attributes: ['id'] });
user.getLists({ attributes: [['user_list', 'random_name']] });
```

My models look like this

**User model:**

```
const user = db.define(
  'user',
  {
    id: {
      type: sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: sequelize.STRING,
      unique: 'email_unique',
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        isEmail: true,
      },
    },
});
```

**List model:**

```
const list = db.define(
  'list',
  {
    id: {
      type: sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
);
```

**UserList:**

```
const userList = db.define(
  'user_list',
  {
    owner: {
      type: sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
);
```

**Associations:**

```
User.belongsToMany(
    List,
    {
      through: UserList,
      as: {
        singular: 'List',
        plural: 'Lists',
      },
    })

List.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserList });
```